# Plotting Variables based on dataframe

Tags: python

I am doing some data analysis for a dataset and this is the variables that i want to plot.

```
neighbourhoods_seniors_no_show = raw_df[raw_df['No_show'] == 1].groupby(['Neighbourhood', 'Age_group']).count()['Gender']
```

resulting in this df group

```
    Neighbourhood  Age_group
AEROPORTO      Adult          1
ANDORINHAS     Adult        269
               Infant        84
               Senior        75
               Teenage       62
                           ... 
UNIVERSITÁRIO  Teenage        2
VILA RUBIM     Adult         71
               Infant        20
               Senior        33
               Teenage       12
Name: Gender, Length: 309, dtype: int64
```

I want to plot a graph showing the Senior Age group with maximum No-shows at each location?

Any idea how do i go on about this?

Comment: What have you tried yourself? What did you expect, and what did you get instead? Also, please don't include example data or output as images, but instead include them as formatted text in the question. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: Thank you for the tip, I am quite new here. As for what i tried, i tried normal plotting but i don't know how to do multivariable plotting, so i didn't get any results.

Comment: Without further information of what you need exactly and what you tried yourself, people can't really help you. There's questions like these that answer the question how to plot multivariate functions, but it's unclear if that's what you're after. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30336138/how-to-plot-a-multivariate-function-in-python - you should probably be more specific about what type of output you expect and what you tried yourself to achieve it.